# Automorphism of group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is my question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Let $\mathbb{K}[G]$ be the group ring of $G$ over $\mathbb{K}$, recall it is the set of $\mathbb{K}$ formal sums of elements in $G$ with ring structure given by the multiplication in $G$.
>
> Is the group of $\mathbb{K}$ algebra automorphisms of $\mathbb{K}[G]$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Any counterexample or reference would be appreciated for this question.

Thanks in advance for you kind answers!

Comment: Take an automorphism of $\mathbb K$. This should yield a counterexample.

Better question: Algebra automorphisms where we see $\mathbb K [G]$ as a $\mathbb K$-algebra.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks Paul, you are absolutely right, the question is more meaningful for $\mathbb{K}$ algebra automorphisms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Let $G=\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. Then define $\newcommand\CC{\Bbb{C}}\CC[G] \to \CC[G]$
by $g \mapsto \zeta_n^g g$. This is an automorphism of $\CC[G]$ which doesn't arise from an automorphism of the group.

The idea here is that algebra maps $k[G]\to R$, where $R$ is a $k$ algebra correspond to maps from $G$ to $R^\times$. Thus if $\operatorname{Hom}(G,k[G]^\times)$ contains an element other than the ones arising from $G\to G\hookrightarrow k[G]^\times$ such that the $k$-dimension of the span of the image of $G$ is the size of $G$, you're going to get an automorphism that doesn't come from an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Take for example the group ring $\mathbb K[\mathbb Z] $, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb K[t, t^{-1}]$. If the characteristic of the field is not $2$, we can send $t\mapsto -t$ to get an additional automorphism.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is crystal clear!

Comment: @Ramus No problem.